# Recursive downloads following redirects

Tags: linux, download, wget, redirection, curl

## My goals:

1. I want to download all *.zip files on a page where all relevant links are redirects done by a server script ( `*/download.php?standard=yes&file=*.zip` ).
2. I want the original link to be used to name the files, since the name given by the server is in this case always "download.zip".

Specifically, I want to download the OsmAnd maps from here: http://download.osmand.net/rawindexes/

How do I do it?

## What I tried:

I could use `wget` to do something similar with the maps for MAPS.ME:

```
wget -rl1 --accept="mwm" http://direct.mapswithme.com/direct/latest/
```

But in this case the links were direct, and there was no problem with the file names.

I also tried to use `curl -L`, but that's without recursion, and it doesn't seem to work for the kind of redirects that are used on that page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wget works fine but you need to quote the URL since it's not escaped.

i.e.

```
wget 'http://download.osmand.net/download.php?standard=yes&file=Afghanistan_asia_2.obf.zip' -O Afghanistan_asia_2.obf.zip
```

The -O option controls the output name. It should be fairly easy to create a shell script that will do that given a list of filenames.

Edit:
You can get file names by downloading the page and doing a regex search for the file pattern:

```
wget -nv 'http://download.osmand.net/rawindexes/' -O - | grep -oE "file=[A-Za-z0-9_]*.obf.zip" | cut -c6-
```

Which could be combined with xargs and piped directly into wget to download each file:

```
xargs -I{} wget 'http://download.osmand.net/download.php?standard=yes&file={}' -O {}
```

Or your full, one line command (works in Cygwin, other *nix may require some playing with quotes and xargs):

```
wget -nv 'http://download.osmand.net/rawindexes/' -O - | grep -oE "file=[A-Za-z0-9_]*.obf.zip" | cut -c6- | xargs -I{} wget 'http://download.osmand.net/download.php?standard=yes&file={}' -O {}
```

Answer (score 1):

Some filenames have "-" in them. So the script to get the list of files should be changed with one character. This works for me:

```
wget -nv 'http://download.osmand.net/rawindexes/' -O - | grep -oE "file=[A-Za-z0-9_-]*.obf.zip" | cut -c6-
```